# importing modules into anaconda-spyder

Tags: python-2.7, import, module, anaconda, spyder

I am tring to import the code for the module 'printSoln' I have it saved in a file named scicomp as printSoln.py however every time I try to import the module when I run the code I am told there is no module named printSoln wether or not I have the .py at the end of it here is what I have done so far

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy import integrate
import printSoln
from euler0 import *
import pylab as pl
```

Comment: A file scicomp, or a directory?

Comment: its type is a file folder

Comment: since it is not properly installed to your environment, I'm afraid it can't find the path.
Can you try copying the script (module) to your working folder and tell us the result?

Comment: sorry, but what is my 'working folder' ?

Comment: same folder as where you run the code snippet depicted above

Comment: yes it already is thats how it stated sorry I should have explained that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98947/discussion-between-uvar-and-darren).

Comment: I am guessing you are following the book by Kiusalaas?
Make sure the module is contained within a python script (a filename.py file)
from there you can import: ''from filename import printSoln"
then, you just have to make sure all the indentations are correct.